# Verificar que todos los campos de una lista sean iguales

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo dos Listas relacionadas en C#:

```
public class HandlingUnit 
{
  [StringLength(18)]
        [ExcelColumn("Handling Unit")]
        public String HandlingUnit { get; set; }

        [ExcelColumn("Created on")]
        public DateTime DateShipped { get; set; }

        [ExcelColumn("Packaging materials")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public String Material { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [ExcelColumn("Material")]
        public String MaterialNumber { get; set; }
}

 public class Batches
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public String Batch { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public String Delivery { get; set; }
        public String ObjectKey { get; set; }
        public String Sterilizer { get; set; }

        public String Material { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Handling")]
        public String HandlingUnit { get; set; }
        public virtual HandlingUnits Handling {get;set;}

        public int? StatusID { get; set; }
        public virtual StatusHandlingUnit StatusH { get; set; }

        public byte Completed { get; set; }

}
```

Quiero verificar que todos los batch asociados a un Handling Unit en especifico,
tenga el estado = completed de lo contrario que me lance un false o algo asi.
Como podria Realizar esto con Linq ? existe alguna posibilidad?

Comment: Agregue más código y ejemplos de lo que contiene cada `IList<>`.

Comment: Con LINQ puedes hacer consultas a colecciones como si fueran tablas, intenta hacer un join entre las listas

Comment: Eso no responde mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tenés una lista llamada `batches` y una variable `handlingUnitBuscado`, podría ser algo así:

```
batches
  .Where(b => b.HandlingUnit == handlingUnitBuscado)
  .All(b => b.StatusH == StatusHandlingUnit.Completed)
```

Lo que estamos haciendo ahí es:

1. Filtrar la lista, con el `Where`, dejando unicamente los que tienen el handling unit buscado.
2. Comprobando que todos los elementos cumplen la condición de estar en estado Completed, usando `All`.